# How to specify serialize custom type in YamlDotNet?

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

Here is my simple class, where DigitalStorage is a binary serialiazable class. Its source code can be found here:

https://github.com/QualiSystems/Toscana/blob/master/Toscana/Domain/DigitalStorage.cs

```
public class Host
{
    public HostProperties Properties { get; set; }
}

public class HostProperties
{

    [YamlAlias("mem_size")]
    public DigitalStorage MemSize { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to deserialize the following YAML, it fails:

```
host:
    properties:
        mem_size: 4096 MB
```

Here is the exception:

```
YamlDotNet.Core.YamlException : (Line: 16, Col: 22, Idx: 396) - (Line: 16, Col: 29, Idx: 403): Exception during deserialization
----> System.InvalidCastException : Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Toscana.Domain.DigitalStorage'.
at YamlDotNet.Serialization.ValueDeserializers.NodeValueDeserializer.DeserializeValue(EventReader reader, Type expectedType, SerializerState state, IValueDeserializer nestedObjectDeserializer) in C:\projects\yamldotnet\YamlDotNet\Serialization\ValueDeserializers\NodeValueDeserializer.cs:line 75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just add an `implicit operator` to your `DigitalStorage` class, it will convert from a `string` just fine:

```
public class DigitalStorage
{
    public DigitalStorage(string value)
    {
        // TODO: Do whatever you need to convert the string value.
    }

    public static implicit operator DigitalStorage(string value)
    {
        return new DigitalStorage(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Explicit operator will also work here and is - for most uses, I'd say - a better solution.